# perform Fade_out animation android

Tags: android, animation

I want to perform a fade out animation whenever a keyboard click matches with the image that is on the view.
Here is my code for the matching click:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

         @Override 
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { 
            imageView.setAlpha(255);
         }

         @Override 
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

          @Override 
          public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
              imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
            }
        });

        if(counterOfindex==random.length){
            startAnimation();
         }else{
               startAnimation();
               Log.e("removed_id=:", ""+viewId);
            }
```

I want to slowly fade out the image once the right key letter on the keyboard has been clicked.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
     <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" 

      android:duration="4000"/>
 </set>
```

Problem: Nothing is happening. The code runs just as it was running previously.

Comment: `whenever a keyboard click matches with the image that is on the view` What do you mean by this ?

Comment: Actually an image of letters in coming from the top of my view.I need to click the right letter on the keyboard to score.